# Phone number pattern validation in angular material designing

Tags: angular, angular-material

I want to validate phone number using angular material designing code but  below code is not working even when i enter valid phone number ca n some on help me please

```
 <mat-form-field class="example-full-width">
                <input matInput placeholder="Phone number" formControlName="PhoneNumber"
                   [errorStateMatcher]="matcher" [(ngModel)]="PhoneNumber" required pattern="[6-9]\\d{9}" maxlength="10">
                     <mat-hint>Errors appear instantly!</mat-hint>
                     <mat-error *ngIf="emailForm.get('PhoneNumber').hasError('required')">
                       Phone number is <strong>required</strong>
                     </mat-error>
                      <mat-error *ngIf="!emailForm.get('PhoneNumber').hasError('required') &&emailForm.get('PhoneNumber').hasError('pattern')">
                      Please enter valid mumber
                     </mat-error>
          </mat-form-field>

    ngOnInit() {

    //Form Group
    this.emailForm = new FormGroup({
      PhoneNumber:new FormControl('',[Validators.pattern(/^[6-9]\d{9}$/)]),
    });
}
```

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-2m1vdq-7vzaq8?file=app%2Finput-error-state-matcher-example.html

Comment: What do you call a "valid" phone number? Each country will likely have different conventions of how to write them (spaces, dashes, parentheses, etc.) and also different lengths.

Comment: can you please guide me how to validate india phone number

Comment: For those not familiar with Indian phone numbers, could you explicitly state the format you are trying to validate in the question?

Comment: If I understand your requirements properly then I think you need to write regex for your input fields.Similar to your phone number you will need to put validation that in name field user should not be able to enter special characters and numbers.Use regex its simple and easy.

Comment: your PhoneNumber new FormControl param has a misplaced "[" before validators. Move it to after the "(". new FormControl(['',Validators.pattern(/^[6-9]\d{9}$/)])

Answer (score 1):

you can try the below regex it worked for me

/^[0-9]{10,10}$/

Comment: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-2m1vdq-7vzaq8?file=app%2Finput-error-state-matcher-example.html

Answer (score 0):

**Try this,**

```
  ngOnInit() {

    let MOBILE_PATTERN = /[0-9\+\-\ ]/;

    this.emailForm = new FormGroup({
      PhoneNumber:new FormControl('',[Validators.pattern(MOBILE_PATTERN)])
    });
  }
```