# Material input for select Country code and insert phone number in Angular 7

Tags: angular, angular-material, angular7, ngx-international-phone-number

I have form and i am using Angular material library for input, i need standard input for select country code and then insert phone number, there is any solution for this issue?

Answer (score 1):

It's hard to tell from your question, but I believe you're asking for a way to input a phone number and validate that it's the correct format.  You'll have to build your own UI controls, but then you can validate it through Angular Forms like in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54686710/4812782) post.